# Java I have an Array that cannot be resolved across a class

Tags: java, arrays

I have an Array that is in a class called MusicArray 
and I want to be able to print its data and search it in my SearchClass class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Searchclass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

              MusicArray ma = new MusicArray();

         for(int count = 1; count <= songDetails.length; count++){
         System.out.println(SongDetails.length);
         System.out.println(songDetails[count - 1]);}
```

In the MusicArray class I have this

```
 public Music[] getSongDetails() {
        return songDetails;
```

I though that this code snippet made the array availabe to the other classes

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ma` object to retrieve the array, like this:

```
Music[] songDetails = ma.getSongDetails();
```

Then you can iterate over the `Music[]` array.

Comment: Great thanks I knew it would be something simple.  Now when 2 people give you the same right answer whose answer do you accept?

Comment: @Bradley: Throw a coin or award the one that answered first :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use ma.getSongDetails() to access the array from your SearchClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Searchclass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

         MusicArray ma = new MusicArray();
         Music [] details = ma.getSongDetails();

         for(int count = 0; count < details.length; count++)
         {
             System.out.println(details.length);
             System.out.println(details[count]);
         }
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code will probably still have problems.  You don't add any instances of Music to MusicArray, so either the array will be null (you'll see a NullPointerException) or empty (nothing will print.)

Comment: All the data is added to the array in the MusicArray class which I didn't show in my OP.   Its running and printing the data fine.  All I have to do know is write a search method and a menu and I'm done. thanks for your interest and help